# "admissible" maps from context

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, soft-question

I have been reading Massey's Algebraic Topology and on page 158 came across the following "semi-mystical principle" which he says guides much mathematical research:

> Whenever we wish to gain information about a certain class of mathematical objects, it is usually helpful to consider also the appropriate class of admissible maps and automorphisms of these objects.

At the risk of veering into religion, how should "appropriate" and "admissible" be defined in this context?

Comment: I think his point as that we need only consider maps that preserve some property in question. If it's algebraic structure: homomorphisms, continuous maps for topological objects (maybe the stronger homeomprhism), diffeomorphisms for smooth manifolds, or even linear transformations for certain geometric objects. We want to think about what we can garner from such maps. Perhaps category theory would be of interest to you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homological_algebra  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_nonsense